# Protect Chef config when a node is compromised

Tags: security, chef

Imagine that one node of a system gets compromised. If I understand correctly hacker will be able to get all configs for all servers in a system using chef's API. Is that correct? If yes, is there a way to ensure that a node only gets information required for its configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The pem key for that server is unique to that chef organization and node.  That is how it identifies itself to the chef server and makes sure that node attributes pertain to only that node.  Which is why when you change chef-orgs, you have to re-bootstrap the server.  Additionally, when you try to execute using chef-client on a different box with the same pem key or even a rebuilt box with the old pem key, it will not work.

Encrypted data bags stored on the server still require a secret key passed to chef-client from knife.

Comment: But hacker don't need to set up a node on another box. He can just download all cookbooks stored on chef server ant transfer to his box.

Comment: Does no good if they can't populate environment/node attributes.  They'll have a bunch of recipes with a skeletal framework.  They could get the same thing from the chef community repo with less sauce.

Comment: Remember, cookbooks are not configurations - at least they shouldn't be written as such.  They are instructions to build consistency based on role attributes and environmental attributes.